# Samsung KNOX API: Can I change a restriction policy that another app already set?

Tags: android, mdm, samsung-knox

I am playing around with the `com.samsung.knox.example.gettingstarted` app. I gained the developer license from the KNOX portal to do so.

I installed two versions (under different application IDs) of the app on my Samsung device with Android 13:

1. First app calls [`restrictionPolicy.allowSafeMode(false)`](https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/restriction/RestrictionPolicy.html#allowSafeMode(boolean))
2. `restrictionPolicy.isSafeModeAllowed()` returns `false` (as expected)
3. Second app calls `restrictionPolicy.allowSafeMode(true)`
4. `restrictionPolicy.isSafeModeAllowed()` returns `false` (I assumed `true`)

Questions

1. Is that common behavior of the KNOX API across all restrictions?
2. Where's that behavior documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KNOX Tech Support told me "the stronger policy will take precedent". [Example](https://docs.samsungknox.com/admin/knox-platform-for-enterprise/kbas/kba-115013208027/)

In my case `restrictionPolicy.allowSafeMode(false)` is the stronger policy among two.